# .NET AutoFixture without initializing Inherited properties

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofixture

I have a base class from which all my DBEntities inherit certain properties:

```cs
public abstract class DBEntity{
    public virtual string Key { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    // A lot more properties...
}
```

Additionally, I have multiple specific entities, such as:

```cs
public class Car : DBEntity{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int DoorCount{ get; set; }
    // A lot more properties...
}
```

Is there a method to generate objects without initializing the properties inherited from the parent class `DBEntity`? (They should just be the default values)

Currently, for each DBEntity property, I use the following approach:

```cs
_fixture.Customize<Car >(composer =>composer.Without(x => x.Key ));
```